# Show $2(B \cdot \nabla)B = \nabla |B|^2$ when the B-field is curl-less using summation notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, tensor-calculus

I was able to show for myself that 
$$ 2(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla})\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{\nabla} |\mathbf{B}|^2$$ when $\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{B} = 0$, but in order to do this, I had to actually write out all the components in regular (e.g. $B_x\frac{\partial B_x}{B_y} + ...$, etc.)

This is fine, but I would like to be able to present this in a more compact format (and I'm working on improving my familiarity with summation notation). Is there a way to write this proof in Einstein summation notation?

Comment: If the magnetic field vanishes at infinity, then if your magnetic field has both zero divergence (from Gauss's Law for Magnetism) and zero curl, it's the zero field. I assume you're looking at conditions where nonzero field is allowed at infinity, then?

Comment: Yes, @probably_someone -- The setup I have is a magnetic field generated by electromagnets several centimeters away from some nanoparticles, to which a (slowly-varying) magnetic force is being applied. See my previous question: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435636/when-does-nabla-times-b-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the vanishing components *i* of 
$$
\mathbf{B}\times (\nabla \times \mathbf{B})=0,
$$
namely
$$
0= B_j \epsilon^{ijk}( \epsilon ^{klm}\partial_l B_m) = (\delta^{il}\delta^{jm}-\delta^{im}\delta^{jl}) B_j \partial_l B_m \tag{z}\\
= B_j \partial_i B_j -  B_j \partial_j B_i   = \frac{1}{2} \partial_i (B_j B_j)- B_j\partial_j B_i, 
$$
which but amount to the vanishing components of 
$$
0= \frac{1}{2} \nabla (|\mathbf{B}|^2) - (\mathbf{B}\cdot \nabla)~ \mathbf{B}.
$$

The identity (z) above is arguably one of the most useful determinant identities in vector calculus. Check its antisymmetry in the respective pairs of indices.